# Object scaling preventing retargeting of rigify rig to bvh with MakeWalk

Tags: rigging, rigify

I created my rig from rigify armature and it is working beautifully.

The issue now is I want to load some mocap bvh files on it, I'm using MakeWalk addon but when I try to load the bvh file by clicking in "Load and Retarget" button under the Misc Tab I got this error:

[image]

I searched a lot I didn't find any clue to solve this... using a regular rig or makehuman rig would be a pain in the a*% for me since Rigify is amazing and I am pretty used to it.

any tips are welcome thanks

Comment: It is telling you that your rig scale in object mode is not (1,1,1). Select the rig in object mode and hit ctrl-A  and select scale from the menu to apply scale.

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Apply Scale**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply)

The warning indicates the rig scale in object mode is not `(1, 1, 1)` (unity). Select the rig in object mode and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>, or select via the *`Object > Apply > Scale`*  menu, to apply scale.

It's the same process as selecting all bones in edit mode and scaling to match the current size, with unity object scaling.